# Review my layout to see if I've missed anything

Tags: led, schematics, stripboard

This is my first attempt at a schematic to Vero layout so a more educated and experienced set of eyes would be much appreciated. I am also open to suggestions and criticisms.

Also, I'm putting this in a Hammond-style box in the presentation on a guitar pedal for my son so I will probably wire all LEDs off board for easier mounting purposes. ALL of my experience is from DIY guitar pedals on Vero.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A decoupling capacitor on the power supply can't hurt. These aren't fast circuits, so value and type aren't critical, 100nF ceramic or any value of electrolytic will do.

Comment: Absolutely, good call. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some minor wiring errors inside yellow circle. External the sequence of LEDs to be in order is OK. But easier to use jumpers and mount LED's to board in sequence, solder with >= 5mm spacer between board in 3s  max if pre-tinned to avoid gold bondwire shear stress.

Usually better to have all pin 1's facing same way if possible.
Each LED could use 3V battery with no R. only internal R.~ 50.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Circuit Diagram**

I can't see any point in including R3 (10k).

I would considering increasing the size of C1 to say 470nF so that you can reduce the size of R1 and VR1. 1M values are pretty large although the larger values will reduce power consumption.

You need a low value resistor in series with VR1 to set a minimum resistance value otherwise the 555 will stop oscillating when the pot is turned right down.

Consider using low power CMOS 7555, such as the ICM7555, rather than the bipolar 555 which is more power hungry.

**VERO BOARD**

There is no ground connection to the 555 (pin 1).

The cathodes of the LEDs should all be commoned up and connected via the 100R resistor to ground. It looks like the LED cathodes aren't connected to anything and the ground at the bottom is connected to the ground near the top via the 100R resistor.

You have missed off the 8th LED from the pin 10 output.

Comment: I told myself not to forget the LED on pin 10 and I still did. I also forgot to state in original post I would connect all LED cathodes via the jumper P23-F23 if I decided to not mount them in bezels on the enclosure off-board. You pointed out that my bottom row in connected to ground, should it not be? R3 10k is connected to pin 14 of IC2 and pin 3 of IC2 via jumper and then connects to ground on bottom row. I looked at a few different schematics for essentially the same circuit and I thought the 1M VR was high as well. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @DOPE_AF The bottom row isn't connected directly to the top ground, it's connected via the 100R resistor. The two ground rows should be connected directly. The 100R resistor should be in series with the commoned up LED cathodes. What I was trying to say about the 10k resistor is that it is unnecessary to include it, the 555 doesn't need a load to work.